# How to write to an existing excel 10000 times file without deleting the previous data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My code works on Loop

After one process it will generate 100 rows
After second it will generate 160 rows

like that it goes on until 10000 times and nearly 300 million rows.

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Masterfile.xlsx')
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter('Masterfile.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') 
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

df.to_excel(writer, "Main", cols=['Diff1', 'Diff2'])

writer.save()
```

Used this but data is not saving it is still overwriting

my table has 3 columns only and all the output columns are the same.

Code:

```
a = "SELECT id FROM USER WHERE time >'2018-03-01'"
dataa = pd.read_sql_query(a, con=engine)
print(dataa)

for userid in dataa:
   x=f"SELECT idbody FROM col1 WHERE user_id='{userid}'"
   data = pd.read_sql_query(x,con = engine)
```

here i need to append those 1000 userid rows into a single excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use "append" mode, which will append data, without overwriting.

```
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Masterfile.xlsx')

with pandas.ExcelWriter('Masterfile.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer: 
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    df.to_excel(writer, "Main", cols=['Diff1', 'Diff2'])

    writer.save()
```

Comment: it is still overwriting

Comment: Please post a reproducible example or full code (preferably stripped to the bare essence). The "append" mode works for sure, so it's something wrong with your code.

Comment: @hukkemaaruspetus Please put a reproducible example. Forget the database, just put some dummy data and write these in a loop.

Comment: is there a way to append the df rather than the excel file ? Shall i post a another question that proceess may be fast?

Comment: You should post a new question for a new problem. What you're asking likely can be found already on SO. Check `append` function. Don't jump to a new question without resolving this one first.

Comment: @hukkemaaruspetus Yes, append is very slow. You can make it much more efficient by e.g. creating new dataframes (with e.g. 20k rows) and then concatenate them.